# How can I retrieve Id of inserted entity using Entity framework Core?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a concern since as I am new to using EntityFramework Core, that if I add an object, that I still do not have the id generated by the database, sending the object to it in the transaction, I would add it automatically, this is my code ,

```
public async Task<ServiceResult<Common.Entities.Company>> SaveCompany(Domain.Models.Company companyModel, Domain.Models.Administrator administratoModel)
{
    ServiceResult<Common.Entities.Company> serviceResult = new ServiceResult<Common.Entities.Company>();

    try
    {

        if (user == null && companyExistsRnc == false)
        {

            Common.Entities.Company myCompany = new Common.Entities.Company
            {
                CompanyId = companyModel.CompanyId, // The id has not been generated yet,
                CompanyName = companyModel.CompanyName,
                Rnc = companyModel.Rnc,
                CountryId = companyModel.Country.CountryId,
                Telephone = companyModel.Telephone,
                PersonContact = companyModel.PersonContact,
                Address = companyModel.Address,
                PhotoPath = companyModel.PhotoPath,
                IsActive = false,
            };

            await _companyRepository.SaveCompany(myCompany); // this is the method that I add the company object to the database and do the savechanges

            Common.Entities.User myUser = new Common.Entities.User
            {
                FirstName = administratoModel.FirstName,
                SecondName = administratoModel.SecondName,
                FirstLastName = administratoModel.FirstLastName,
                SecondLastName = administratoModel.SecondLastName,
                GenderId = administratoModel.Gender.GenderId,
                PhoneNumber = administratoModel.Telephone,
                Email = administratoModel.Email,
                UserName = administratoModel.Email,
                IsActive = administratoModel.IsActive,
                UserTypeId = (short)Common.Core.UserType.Administrator,
                Company = myCompany, // here I send the my company object for when I do the savechanges, I think it will add it to me
            };

            await _userHelper.AddUserAsync(myUser, administratoModel.Password);
            await _userHelper.AddUserToRoleAsync(myUser, Common.Core.UserType.Administrator.ToString());

            Common.Entities.Administrator myAdministrator = new Common.Entities.Administrator
            {
                AdministratorId = administratoModel.AdministratorId,
                FirstName = administratoModel.FirstName,
                SecondName = administratoModel.SecondName,
                FirstLastName = administratoModel.FirstLastName,
                SecondLastName = administratoModel.SecondLastName,
                GenderId = administratoModel.Gender.GenderId,
                Email = administratoModel.Email,
                Telephone = administratoModel.Telephone,
                IsActive = true,
                PhotoPath = administratoModel.PhotoPath,
                UserTypeId = (short)Common.Core.UserType.Administrator,
                Company = myCompany, // company object without the id
                User = myUser, // user object without the id
            };

            await _administratorRepository.SaveAdministrator(myAdministrator);

            serviceResult.Data = myCompany;
            serviceResult.Message = "Compañia agregada!";
        }
    }
```

I am new to using entity framework core, and if in case I am wrong in what I am doing please indicate in which part I am doing it wrong, to correct, I await your comments and would appreciate the help,

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: As it is obvious, you are using Repository pattern to connect to DB. In order to return the generated Id from database, you should modify Repository functions such as your SaveAdministrator() not the function you posted above.

Comment: What SaveAdministrator contains is a savechanges to the database and a dispose (), the question is if what I'm doing is right